# Parallel execution of a for loop in java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, executorservice

I have used the ExecutorService and FutureTask in java to perform a parallel operation in a for loop. Following is the code

```
package com.sample.threading.parallel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

public class Combinations { 
   public static String[] fillArray(int range) {
        String a[] = new String[100];
        for (int i = ((10 * range) + 1); i < (10 * (range + 1)); i++) {
            a[i] = "Name " + i;
        }
        return a;
    }


    public static String[] futureFillArray() throws Exception {
        String a[] = new String[100];
        int threadNum = 2;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadNum);
        List<FutureTask<String[]>> taskList = new ArrayList<FutureTask<String[]>>();

        FutureTask<String[]> futureTask = new FutureTask<String[]>(
                new Callable<String[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public String[] call() throws Exception {
                        return fillArray(0);
                    }
                });

        taskList.add(futureTask);
        executor.execute(futureTask);

        FutureTask<String[]> futureTask1 = new FutureTask<String[]>(
                new Callable<String[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public String[] call() throws Exception {
                        return fillArray(1);
                    }
                });

        taskList.add(futureTask1);
        executor.execute(futureTask1);

        FutureTask<String[]> futureTask2 = new FutureTask<String[]>(
                new Callable<String[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public String[] call() throws Exception {
                        return fillArray(2);
                    }
                });

        taskList.add(futureTask2);
        executor.execute(futureTask2);

        FutureTask<String[]> futureTask3 = new FutureTask<String[]>(
                new Callable<String[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public String[] call() throws Exception {
                        return fillArray(3);
                    }
                });

        taskList.add(futureTask3);
        executor.execute(futureTask3);

        for (int j = 0; j < threadNum; j++) {
            FutureTask<String[]> futureTaskF = taskList.get(j);
            a = futureTaskF.get();
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        return a;
    }
}
```

I know that i have to call the fillArray method 10 times but i have called only three times. The following is the execution class

```
package com.sample.threading.parallel;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class ExecuteCombinations {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         long timeStart = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            String res[] = Combinations.fillArray(0);
            long timeEnd = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            long timeNeeded = timeEnd - timeStart;
            System.out.println("Result         : " + res + " calculated in " + timeNeeded + " ms");

            // Parallel execution
            long timeStartFuture = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            String res2[] = Combinations.futureFillArray();
            long timeEndFuture = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            long timeNeededFuture = timeEndFuture - timeStartFuture;
            System.out.println("Result (Future): " + res2 + " calculated in " + timeNeededFuture + " ms");
    }
}
```

but still the following is the output

```
Result         : [Ljava.lang.String;@773d3f62 calculated in 0 ms
Result (Future): [Ljava.lang.String;@47b6617 calculated in 16 ms
```

Is my implementation wrong? Please advise

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? Why do you expect it that way?

Comment: I would like to know how the for loop is being executed parallel by many threads. If the execution is parallel then shouldnt it take less time than the single thread calling the function "fillArray" once?

Comment: If you want to fill **all** array faster than in single thread, you should fill the same array in each task - now you are creating new array in each task and fill 10 fields in it. 
BTW you will never set array[0] - you are starting from 1 in `fillArray(0)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. You're wondering why you only get two lines of output despite running 3 Futures, right? If that's the case, you only have to adjust the printing of your `String res2[] = Combinations.futureFillArray();` (i.e using a `for`-loop iterating over all the entries in `res2[]` to see all the results.